# Wordpress fronted having issue and not working give the error like database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, frontend, database-connection

Can you please help me to resolve the below issue?

I am working on the WordPress project where my backed open is successfully but when i open the front side it is giving me an error like below.

[image]

Please Help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with naming some of tour values in this specified file:
`/var/www/html/web/wp/wp-includes/wp-db.php`

And it appears `on line 1653`, make sure to get into this file and find the error-making line to see what could be possibly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue due to change the CHARTYPE. i think i was facing some CHARTYPE issue.
Now my issue is resolved now.

Thanks.